# Is it possible to set the duration of a GrowlNotify notification?

Tags: notifications, growl

Looking to speed up Growl notifications on a per-application basis (doesn't seem possible within Growl's own GUI), I'm sceptical but still curious if this is possible via GrowlNotify:

Does anyone know whether it's possible to set the duration of a GrowlNotify notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command line tool [growlnotify](http://growl.info/extras.php#growlnotify) to make a sticky notification, but unfortunately, you can't set a specific time. Here are the commands:

```
growlnotify -s
```

It will prompt you:

```
Enter a notification description, followed by newline, followed by Ctrl-D (End of File). To cancel, press Ctrl-C.
```

Make sure you hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, *then* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. The resulting notification will stay up as long as you don't click the "X" in the corner.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks. So it's not really possible to set a duration for separate notifications. Alas, this quite fables me, since you can set all kinds of doohickeys like styles, etc.

Comment: @hced No, AFAIK, there's no way to set a time for the notification. I wish!!

Answer (score 2):

You can kind of do this with Growl GUI, not the best approach, but should work:

With the Grown GUI you can set event duration per-style. You can also assign styles per application.

So, if you assign different styles to different applications, you can achieve the desired effect. But that would result in different visual styles for different applications, which may not be desired. You may also be able to duplicate styles (don't know how) and assign styles that are the same visually to different applications. Alternatively you may be able to create new styles based on existing ones.

Again, not the best solution but should works.